# SQL procedure parameter

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures, procedure

I am trying to do a procedure in sql but I have some trouble with date parameters

```
DELIMITER #
CREATE PROCEDURE conso(IN p_upcNameId VARCHAR(20), IN p_dateFrom DATE, IN p_dateTo DATE)     
BEGIN
    DECLARE done int default false;

    DECLARE v_cumule FLOAT;

    DECLARE v_reserve VARCHAR(40);
    DECLARE v_kg VARCHAR(40);
    DECLARE v_date DATETIME;

    DECLARE v_reserve_1 VARCHAR(40);
    DECLARE v_kg_1 VARCHAR(40);
    DECLARE v_date_1 DATETIME;

    DECLARE cur1 CURSOR FOR
        SELECT reserve, kg, date
        FROM
        (
            ( SELECT event_param_3 as reserve, event_param_4 as kg, event_datetime as date FROM events WHERE upcNameId = p_upcNameId AND event_code = 50 ORDER BY event_datetime DESC )
            UNION
            ( SELECT event_param_2 as reserve, event_param_3 as kg, event_datetime as date FROM events WHERE upcNameId = p_upcNameId AND event_code = 54 ORDER BY event_datetime DESC )

            UNION
            ( SELECT event_param_2 as reserve, event_param_3 as kg, event_datetime as date FROM events WHERE upcNameId = p_upcNameId AND event_code = 52 ORDER BY event_datetime DESC )
            UNION
            ( SELECT event_param_1 as reserve, event_param_2 as kg, event_datetime as date FROM events WHERE upcNameId = p_upcNameId AND event_code = 56 ORDER BY event_datetime DESC )

            UNION
            ( SELECT event_param_2 as reserve, event_param_3 as kg, event_datetime as date FROM events WHERE upcNameId = p_upcNameId AND event_code = 53 ORDER BY event_datetime DESC )
            UNION
            ( SELECT event_param_1 as reserve, event_param_2 as kg, event_datetime as date FROM events WHERE upcNameId = p_upcNameId AND event_code = 57 ORDER BY event_datetime DESC )
        ) as diffusion_programs
        ORDER BY date DESC;
    DECLARE cur2 CURSOR FOR
        SELECT reserve, kg, date
        FROM
        (
            ( SELECT event_param_3 as reserve, event_param_4 as kg, event_datetime as date FROM events WHERE upcNameId = p_upcNameId AND event_code = 50 ORDER BY event_datetime DESC )
            UNION
            ( SELECT event_param_2 as reserve, event_param_3 as kg, event_datetime as date FROM events WHERE upcNameId = p_upcNameId AND event_code = 54 ORDER BY event_datetime DESC )

            UNION
            ( SELECT event_param_2 as reserve, event_param_3 as kg, event_datetime as date FROM events WHERE upcNameId = p_upcNameId AND event_code = 52 ORDER BY event_datetime DESC )
            UNION
            ( SELECT event_param_1 as reserve, event_param_2 as kg, event_datetime as date FROM events WHERE upcNameId = p_upcNameId AND event_code = 56 ORDER BY event_datetime DESC )

            UNION
            ( SELECT event_param_2 as reserve, event_param_3 as kg, event_datetime as date FROM events WHERE upcNameId = p_upcNameId AND event_code = 53 ORDER BY event_datetime DESC )
            UNION
            ( SELECT event_param_1 as reserve, event_param_2 as kg, event_datetime as date FROM events WHERE upcNameId = p_upcNameId AND event_code = 57 ORDER BY event_datetime DESC )
        ) as diffusion_programs
        WHERE date >= p_dateFrom;
        AND date <= p_dateTo;
        ORDER BY date DESC;
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = 1;
    OPEN cur1;
    OPEN cur2;

    /* Create temporary table */
    CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmp
    (
        date DATE,
        kg FLOAT
    );
    SET v_cumule = 0;
    FETCH cur2 INTO v_reserve_1, v_kg_1, v_date_1;

    forLoop: LOOP
        /* Actual row */
        FETCH cur1 INTO v_reserve, v_kg, v_date;

        /* Next row */
        FETCH cur2 INTO v_reserve_1, v_kg_1, v_date_1;

        /* Reserves differents TODO */
        /*IF v_reserve != v_reserve_1
        END IF;*/

        IF DATE(v_date) = DATE(v_date_1) THEN SET v_cumule = v_cumule + (v_kg_1 - v_kg);
        ELSE
            INSERT INTO tmp VALUES (DATE(v_date), v_cumule);
            SET v_cumule = 0;
        END IF;

        IF done THEN LEAVE forLoop;
        END IF;
    END LOOP;

    CLOSE cur1;
    CLOSE cur2;
END#
```

You see p_datefrom and p_dateto are some parameter that I want to pass when I call the function with :

```
DELIMITER ;
CALL conso('Name','2017-01-01','2018-01-01');
SELECT * FROM tmp;
```

As you can see this is an interval of dates.
But I get this error :

1064 - Erreur de syntaxe près de 'AND date <= p_dateTo;
        ORDER BY date DESC;
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER' à la ligne 53

Can you help me please ?

Comment: Are you using MySQL or Oracle (plsql)?

Comment: I am using Mysql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's some spurious semicolons (statement terminators).

```
  WHERE date >= p_dateFrom;
       AND date <= p_dateTo;
       ORDER BY date DESC;
```

Remove those

```
  WHERE date >= p_dateFrom
       AND date <= p_dateTo
       ORDER BY date DESC
  ;
```

---

*original (wrong) answer*:

<strike>The `CONTINUE HANDLER` has to follow the variable declarations, but needs to be *before* the cursor declarations. (I think this is vaguely documented in the MySQL Reference Manual. MySQL stored programs are very particular about the order of statements.)</strike>

To fix that error, just move the `DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER` statement to right before the first `DECLARE CURSOR`.

Comment: I moved the continue handler statement just before the declare cur1 cursor. I get this error : #1338 - Cursor declaration after handler declaration

Comment: Acckk.. My bad. MySQL *is* particular about the order, you had it right, I got it wrong. I see some spurious semicolons that should be removed.

Comment: This is it. The semicolons was the error, thank you ! I managed to run the procedure but I don't have data displaying anymore, but that's not the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

'date' is a reserved word in MySQL. Use another alias.

Also, you should consider using a CASE-statement to get rid of the multiple UNION statements (you can make all UNION's in one query).

EDIT:
The error comes from the fact that you had extra semicolons as spencer7593 already pointed out.

The event_param_X columns are declared as varchar's yet you are doing arithmetic operations (+-) with those.

Comment: I have changed date into day thanks, but sadly it wasn't enough to solve the error.

Comment: To be a little more precise, in MySQL,  `DATE` is a *keyword* but it is not a *reserved word*. (Best practice is to avoid using both reserved words and keywords as identifiers, so I concur with the advice about using a different alias.)

Comment: Yes, that is correct. With closer look at the procedure, there is other problems.